# jquery auto add form input textarea from multi line input triggered by each newline

Tags: jquery, html

i have created [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mofared/d2f7j5fk/2/) here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count

 $(function(){
    $('body').on('paste','.last',function(){
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $('body').append('<div><textarea class="last" type="text" name="text'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" rows="1" cols="50" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
                           }
                                             })
         $('body').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })

         $('body').on('keydown','.last',function(e){

             if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                 e.preventDefault();
            x++; //text box increment
            $('body').append('<div><textarea class="last" type="text" name="text'+(Number($(this).attr('name').match(/[0-9]+/g))+1)+'" rows="1" cols="50" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });    
 })        
 });
```

Right now i only managed to make textarea input to trigger on enter keycode and paste event. How can i make the input to trigger by each new line /n so that every time i paste the data, new line input would have their own field area.

Comment: A newline character that lands in the textarea via paste does not constitute an “event” that you could handle on its own. You’ll need to `split` the value in your `paste` event handler yourself.